# How to append component to body but communicate with parent?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to do modals in VueJS 2.0.

My goal is to call it from wherever in DOM is it possible and render component as child of body but communicate with component where it was initialized.

What I have tried is:

```
...
mounted () {
   document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].appendChild(this.$el);
}
...
```

Which of course renders element where I want it to be rendered and also communicate with component where it was initialized. But when I try to remove it... I get:

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.
```

The way I show / hide model in component where modal is initialized including parameter visible: true / false and then:

```
<modal v-if="visible"></modal>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Question: Why the dynamic insertion and removal of the component? Why not have it always there and just show/hide as needed?

Comment: I would like to use it for modal... I found a workaround. I saved context where the element was triggered to vuex and also trigger show of desired modal trough vuex. And by doing that I am able to pass data to context. I believe that this is not the best solution and therefor I wait for a better one - if any. Otherwise I will paste my answer here.